# Can you access Kinect motion sensing from XNA?

Tags: xna, xbox360, motion-control

As of 2010 with the release of XNA 4.0, if I buy an Xbox 360 with Kinect will I be able to access its motion sensing data with the XNA game I'm developing? Or is this only restricted to C++ developers with a devkit?

Comment: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/31685/Microsoft_XNA_Will_Support_Kinect_Eventually.php

Comment: To expand on Tetrad's RTFM, the article he links to states...

"Users of Microsoft's free XNA Studio development tools will, at some point, be able to develop games that use Xbox 360's Kinect sensor, according to one Microsoft developer advocate."

Kind of ironic you can't get to the device from XNA, but you can from a Mac or PC.

Comment: @Tim: Just wait for 4.1 or 5, they're probably working on Kinect support right now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> "The non-commercial Kinect SDK for Windows will be released this spring, Microsoft said, and a commercial version is planned for a later date. The company said the SDKs will include support for audio, the Kinect API and direct control of the sensor."

That being said, if you don't want to wait, there's a lot of work being done on several fronts with support for a number of languages (C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, ...) under Windows, Mac and Linux.

For the freshest 0-day Kinect hacks, read [KinectHacks](http://www.KinectHacks.net) and [FreeNect](http://www.freenect.com)

If you want to get started writing code, have a look at these:

- [Code Laboratories](http://codelaboratories.com/) released **CL NUI Platform drivers** for the Kinect, which also includes samples in several languages including C#. The latest 1.0.0.1210 seems to not work ATM, so maybe stick to the older version (1.0.0.1121).
- I got started in minutes using the [KinectTouch C# project](http://get.essexconsolerepairs.co.uk/kinecttouch/) together with CL NUI drivers.
- For motion detection, check out the **haar detection** function inside **OpenCV** or the cross-platform .Net wrapper [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Included are about 20 detection algorithms (XML files) for detecting e.g. hands, eyes, upper-torso, etc. A tool is also included to make your own. Google *haar detect* for more info.
- The [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) project is in charge of **libfreenect** and has sample source code to get you started. AFAIK you will have to use [libusb-win32](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) to interface to the Kinect (which I was too lazy to get working in C#).
- [OpenNI](http://openni.org/) just released an updated driver with Kinect support including sample source code for **skeleton tracking** using their **PrimeSense PSDK**.

Answer (score 9):

http://www.computerandvideogames.com/article.php?id=258873?cid=OTC-RSS&attr=CVG-News-RSS

Looks like for the moment it's only for select Microsoft partners.

Comment: Nice info but I'm leaving this question open for the future, when MS does add support to XNA for Kinect we should be the first ones to know.

Answer (score 2):

**Kinect for Windows SDK Version 1** is now out (since February 2012) and includes commercial support, raw sensor streams, skeletal tracking, and a number of other improvements:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/

Answer (score 1):

I asked the Team XNA about this a few weeks ago and they told me that currently that will not be available via the XNA Framework.

I´m sure they´ll open the Kinect development some day, I just don´t think that will be soon.

Comment: That day is now!

Answer (score 1):

Latest news is that Microsoft will be coming out with a no0n-commercial version of an SDK for Kinect in Spring.Below is the link from Microsoft.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/kinectforwindowssdk-022111.aspx

Comment: +1 I know the question is old, but I think the answer should be kept up to date. It's a yes since they're coming out with an SDK in spring.

Answer (score 1):

This question is tagged Xbox360. While the current version of the SDK (v1-M6) is compatible with XNA, it is windows only, sadly you will have to wait for XBox support.

Answer (score -1):

It should be able to now. They have devolped a driver pack and they did it with Windows 8 in mind. I can't think of what it's called but if you go to Microsoft Dreamspark it's in there. I just saw it earler hope that helps.

Comment: Why not search for it real quick and post the link? As it is this answer isn't very good.