# What do I need to learn so I can make games on XBox Kinect?

Tags: xbox360, books, kinect

I am interested to learn more about game development especially on XBox Kinect. What do I need to learn and what books I should read so I can make games on XBox Kinect?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you take this to [GameDev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) - this is right up their alley.

Comment: Right now, unless you are a licensed Xbox 360 developer, you cannot make Kinect games. (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/can-you-access-kinect-motion-sensing-from-xna.) To become a licensed Xbox 360 developer you need to make business arrangements with Microsoft; the details of that process are personal and usually under NDA.

Comment: Maths Books and Programming Books for Both Hardware and Software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the minute there is no support in XNA for Kinect (although, hopefully this will change in the near future).

There are two ways to develop for Kinect at the moment.

The first is to become a licensed Xbox developer (although it might be a little expensive :P)

The second is to use the open source drivers for Kinect known as OpenKinect (libfreenect, they're interchangeable I think)

The open source libraries can be found here: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page

They are a C library and I think you'll probably need to develop in Linux to make stuff now, but I believe work is being done for support for Windows. Of course, you'll only be able to develop PC applications for the moment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I find it ironic you can't develop Microsoft Kinect programs in a Microsoft OS.

Comment: +1 definitely agreed. But I suppose it's down to how easily (used in the loosest possible way) low level you can get in Linux compared to Windows. Hope the Microsoft versions come out fairly soon though, I like Visual Studio :P