# Developing Kinect game for Xbox360?

Tags: xna, .net, kinect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you access Kinect motion sensing from XNA?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/can-you-access-kinect-motion-sensing-from-xna)

bunch of questions:

- Is it possible for me to create a Kinect application using XNA and deploy it to Xbox360 platform?
- What should I use, will Kinect SDK for Windows be okay for this task?
- What about licenses, is it free to use or should I pay for licenses?

Thanks for any answer or url...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in Kinect support in XNA currently, so any Kinect development on the Xbox 360 is out of the question. If it is one day introduced, it may well be similar to the available Windows SDK, but  there has been nothing announced.

As for licenses and fees, you can develop for the Xbox 360 if you have a $99 AppHub account, available from http://create.msdn.com/en-US